# How can remove and get elements when windows size change

Tags: javascript

How can remove and get elements when windows size change like Twitter ?

I can't understand how twitter removed the right widget when windows size 133% from html and if i change back to the default windows size 100% get back the widget code again to html !!

I can make it to remove from html but can't return it back again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use media queries based on the viewport width.

**Media Query Example**

Make sure to put this in your HTML:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 500px) {
    .element {
        display: block;
    }
}    
@media (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 1000px) {
    .element {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure i know this, but twitter not used display none twitter removed the html code of the element i can't make this by css i will be needed write the codes 2 time in the left and 2 time in the right.

Comment: In this case, you will need to use a javascript solution. Is it necessary you remove the HTML code?

Comment: Yes and i know that i must use a javascript code sure, Thanks for your help :)